# Should I create NT Authenticated Logins mapped to Active Directory groups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, active-directory

We want to use Active Directory groups to restrict access to SQL Server 2005 databases. I see that you can create an Login in SQL (using Windows authentication) mapped to an AD group, but is this a good idea? The obvious benefit is that we would be able to maintain group membership through AD, which we already do for network access and various applications. **Are there any other benefits? What about drawbacks?** I imagine it could get a bit hairy if an AD user belongs to multiple AD groups that exist as separate Logins.

My current plan to create Schemas to contain the various groups of securable database objects. Then I'd create users with the appropriate default Schema and only give access to other Schemas if they need it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you cannot change the default schema of a user mapped to an AD group Login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map a "SQL login" to an AD group: you grant access to an AD group at the SQL level. I say this because "SQL Login" implies username and password.

In any event, it's easier to manage AD groups. And what would your alternatives be in practice?

If a user is in two AD groups, then you need controls to check this. Or use a Logon trigger to test for multiple memberships and reject access

Comment: For network security, if a user is in two groups they are granted access of both groups. I guess it doesn't work the same way when a Logins in SQL are mapped to groups?

Comment: The alternative would be to create database roles and maintain membership through SSMS instead of AD. We've already got users and groups in AD.

Comment: A user in 2 AD groups has both sets of SQL Server permissions assigned to the groups/logins/users

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports two kinds of logins: SQL authenticated, and NT authenticated. You are describing NT authentication. For years, both Microsoft, industry experts, and just about every book I've read strongly recommend using only NT authentication, and *not* using SQL authentication at all. In fact, you can disable SQL authentication, but you cannot disable NT authentication.

In other words, yes, this is the way to go.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. But what about a Login mapped to an AD group?